# Scala - foreach is not a member of Int

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop, int, each

I'm fairly new to Scala and have to write a program which calculates the average of given List of Integers.

However, I always get the error:

> foreach is not a member of Int.

Does anybody of you know how to solve this? Here is my code:

```
 var measureResults = List(100, 36, 54, 4, 22, 37, 86, 20, 3000)

 var averageResult = getAverage(measureResults)

 println(averageResult)

 def getAverage(measureResults: List[Int]): Double = {
    var entryList = listOfValidElements(measureResults)
    var average = entryList(0)
    for (element <- average){
      average =+ 1 
      var trueAverage = average/length(entryList)
      return trueAverage
   }
 }
```

Comment: 1) Please indent you code. 2) Please include the error in your question. 3) `average` is probably an `Int` on wich `<-` makes no sense. 4) Calculating the average of `L` is done by `sum(L)/len(L)`.

Comment: Any reason why you're calculating average using Java-like code with mutable variables and `for` loops instead of just writing `list.sum / list.size`?

Comment: In case you want to calculate avg. you must add all elements to each other and divide them by their count.

Comment: Please replace your code with a minimal example that exhibits the error. As it stands, this question has little lasting value and should probable be closed -- for someone who runs into the same error, the code sample is overly convoluted. For someone looking to compute an average in Scala, a simpler, more direct question would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To actually answer the question as asked

> However I always get the error: foreach is not a member of Int.
>
> Does anybody of you know how to solve this?

in you code here:

```
var average = entryList(0)
for (element <- average){
```

you take the first entry in `entryList`, which is an Int. You then try to iterate over it, which doesn't make any sense, and causes the error you get

You probably meant something like

```
var average  = 0
for (element <- entryList) {
```

(and `average += element` not `average += 1`)

but as others have pointed out, there are much better ways of calculating this in Scala

Answer (score 5):

A more Scala-ish approach,

```
def average(list: List[Int]): Double = {
  list.sum.toDouble / list.size
}
```

Note there is no return statement, the last expression is returned; and no mutability is involved. Casting the sum to `Double` ensures a floating-point division and result. The method name omits *get* prefix for conciseness and eventually to convey with a non-getter class method.

From these notes, `var measureResults = List(1,2,3)` may become immutable, `val measureResults = List(1,2,3)`.

Comment: A more scalish approach: `def average(list: List[Int]): Double = list.sum.toDouble / list.size` :-)

Comment: It's unfortunate that this is marked as the answer, since it doesn't even attempt to answer the question (and it answers another question that should be asked more directly/succinctly).